# MySQL Update all values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `original` and `original_backup`, I'm creating a rollback script that takes all the data from `original_backup` and puts it back into `original`, the issue I have is there are around 60 columns. Is there an easy way to move all data using an `UPDATE` and `SET` without specifying every column?

For example something like:
`UPDATE original SET * FROM original_backup WHERE original.id = original_backup.id;`

Using `REPLACE` is NOT an option in this case.

Comment: no it is not possible

Comment: You could do it in about 6 statements with an [IODKU](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and a real [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as a two step thing:

```
DELETE FROM original
INSERT INTO original SELECT * FROM original_backup
```

This will take some time. To cut over more cleanly:

```
CREATE TABLE original_restored AS SELECT * FROM original_backup
RENAME TABLE original TO original_prev, original_restored TO original
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the my solution but im not use UPDATE statement:

**1) Delete all data from original**

**2) run select insert query**

something like this:

```
INSERT INTO original (Field1, Field2)
SELECT a.Field1, a.Field2
FROM original_backup a
INNER JOIN original b ON a.ID = b.ID
```